# Python - multiprocessing for matplotlib griddata

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, datagrid, multiprocessing

Following my former question [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767235/python-multi-processing-to-mount-an-array), I would like to apply multiprocessing to matplotlib's `griddata` function. Is it possible to split the griddata into, say 4 parts, one for each of my 4 cores? I need this to improve performance.

For example, try the code below, experimenting with different values for `size`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import time

size = 500

Y = np.arange(size)
X = np.arange(size)
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
u = x * np.sin(5) + y * np.cos(5)
v = x * np.cos(5) + y * np.sin(5)
test = x + y

tic = time.clock()

test_d = mlab.griddata(
    x.flatten(), y.flatten(), test.flatten(), x+u, y+v, interp='linear')

toc = time.clock()

print 'Time=', toc-tic
```

Comment: I dont think you can apply multiprocessing. perhaps, this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7424777/566035 is helpful?

Comment: The sample code is not syntactically correct.  What did you intend to do with the following line:  

`test= xx+yy`

Comment: I fixed the code, it should run now.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution :)

Answer (score 5):

I ran the example code below in Python 3.4.2, with numpy version 1.9.1 and matplotlib version 1.4.2, on a Macbook Pro with 4 physical CPUs (i.e., as opposed to "virtual" CPUs, which the Mac hardware architecture also makes available for some use cases):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import time
import multiprocessing

# This value should be set much larger than nprocs, defined later below
size = 500

Y = np.arange(size)
X = np.arange(size)
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
u = x * np.sin(5) + y * np.cos(5)
v = x * np.cos(5) + y * np.sin(5)
test = x + y

tic = time.clock()

test_d = mlab.griddata(
    x.flatten(), y.flatten(), test.flatten(), x+u, y+v, interp='linear')

toc = time.clock()

print('Single Processor Time={0}'.format(toc-tic))

# Put interpolation points into a single array so that we can slice it easily
xi = x + u
yi = y + v
# My example test machine has 4 physical CPUs
nprocs = 4
jump = int(size/nprocs)

# Enclose the griddata function in a wrapper which will communicate its
# output result back to the calling process via a Queue
def wrapper(x, y, z, xi, yi, q):
    test_w = mlab.griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
    q.put(test_w)

# Measure the elapsed time for multiprocessing separately
ticm = time.clock()

queue, process = [], []
for n in range(nprocs):
    queue.append(multiprocessing.Queue())
    # Handle the possibility that size is not evenly divisible by nprocs
    if n == (nprocs-1):
        finalidx = size
    else:
        finalidx = (n + 1) * jump
    # Define the arguments, dividing the interpolation variables into
    # nprocs roughly evenly sized slices
    argtuple = (x.flatten(), y.flatten(), test.flatten(),
                xi[:,(n*jump):finalidx], yi[:,(n*jump):finalidx], queue[-1])
    # Create the processes, and launch them
    process.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=wrapper, args=argtuple))
    process[-1].start()

# Initialize an array to hold the return value, and make sure that it is
# null-valued but of the appropriate size
test_m = np.asarray([[] for s in range(size)])
# Read the individual results back from the queues and concatenate them
# into the return array
for q, p in zip(queue, process):
    test_m = np.concatenate((test_m, q.get()), axis=1)
    p.join()

tocm = time.clock()

print('Multiprocessing Time={0}'.format(tocm-ticm))

# Check that the result of both methods is actually the same; should raise
# an AssertionError exception if assertion is not True
assert np.all(test_d == test_m)
```

and I got the following result:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/tri/triangulation.py:110: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.self._neighbors)
Single Processor Time=8.495998
Multiprocessing Time=2.249938
```

I'm not really sure what is causing the "future warning" from triangulation.py (evidently my version of matplotlib did not like something about the input values that were originally provided for the question), but regardless, the multiprocessing <s>does appear to achieve the desired speedup of 8.50/2.25 = 3.8</s>, (*edit: see comments*) which is roughly in the neighborhood of about 4X that we would expect for a machine with 4 CPUs.  And the assertion statement at the end also executes successfully, proving that the two methods get the same answer, so in spite of the slightly weird warning message, I believe that the code above is a valid solution.

---

EDIT: A commenter has pointed out that both my solution, as well as the code snippet posted by the original author, are likely using the wrong method, `time.clock()`, for measuring execution time; he suggests using `time.time()` instead.  I think I'm also coming around to his point of view.  (Digging into the Python documentation a bit further, I'm still not convinced that even this solution is 100% correct, as newer versions of Python appear to have deprecated `time.clock()` in favor of [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) and [`time.process_time()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html#time.process_time).  But regardless, I do agree that whether or not `time.time()` is absolutely the most correct way of taking this measurement, it's still probably more correct than what I had been using before, `time.clock()`.)

Assuming the commenter's point is correct, then it means the approximately 4X speedup that I thought I had measured is in fact wrong.

However, that does not mean that the underlying code itself wasn't correctly parallelized; rather, it just means that parallelization didn't actually help in this case; splitting up the data and running on multiple processors didn't improve anything.  Why would this be?  Other users have [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941459/is-it-possible-to-know-which-scipy-numpy-functions-run-on-multiple-cores) that, at least in numpy/scipy, some functions run on multiple cores, and some do not, and it can be a seriously challenging research project for an end-user to try to figure out which ones are which.

Based on the results of this experiment, if my solution correctly achieves parallelization within Python, but no further speedup is observed, then I would suggest the simplest likely explanation is that matplotlib is probably also parallelizing some of its functions "under the hood", so to speak, in compiled C++ libraries, just like numpy/scipy already do.  Assuming that's the case, then the correct answer to this question would be that nothing further can be done: further parallelizing in Python will do no good if the underlying C++ libraries are already silently running on multiple cores to begin with.

Comment: Unfortunately you're not computing wall clock time using ``time.clock()`` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23325328/1510289). Instead, use ``time.time()`` and notice that multiprocessing scenario takes actually longer. It's a nice try, though! I too have tried splitting the input values myself and found no speedup to ``griddata()`` whatsoever. :(

Comment: Sorry but @stachyra's answer is incorrect. Substituting ``time.clock()`` with ``time.time()`` the true wall clock performance is worse. My 8-CPU machine gives: ``Single Processor Time=8.833 Multiprocessing Time=11.677``

Comment: I cant launch it... i got an error : "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap  
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-2-9885522fee1f>", line 11, in wrapper
    test_w = mlab.griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/mlab.py", line 2619, in griddata
    raise ValueError("output grid must have constant spacing"
ValueError: output grid must have constant spacing when using interp='linear'..."

Comment: @user3601754: Your version of matplotlib is likely out of date.  As I stated at the beginning of my answer, I ran my code above under Python version 3.4.2, with matplotlib version 1.4.2.  I also happen to have an older installation of Python 2.7.5 available on the same test machine, which uses matplotlib version 1.1.1.  When I try to run my solution code using those older version numbers, I get exactly the same error that you do.   Try upgrading matplotlib to the latest version, and that will almost certainly fix the issue.