# Native numpy parallelization - multiplication and sum/average

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parallel-processing

Is there a way to enable automatic parallelization for basic numpy operations, like element-wise multiplication of arrays and basic numpy functions like np.sum and np.average?

I know that it is possible for blas/lapack functions, as discussed for scipy.linalg.solve in this thread:

[Is it possible to know which SciPy / NumPy functions run on multiple cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941459/is-it-possible-to-know-which-scipy-numpy-functions-run-on-multiple-cores/6942523#6942523)

And I managed to run this code natively in parallel via MKL:

```
import numpy

def test():
    n = 5000
    data = numpy.random.random((n, n))
    result = numpy.linalg.inv(data)

test();
```

But I would need to run something like this in parallel:

```
   N = 1024    
   A = np.zeros((N,N,N),dtype='float32')    
   B = np.zeros((N,N,N),dtype='float32')
   C = np.zeros((N,N,N),dtype='float32')

   A[:,:,:] = 1
   B[:,:,:] = 2

   # this is the part I want parallel
   C[:,:,:] = A[:,:,:]*B[:,:,:]

   # also this:
   avgC = np.average(C)
```

Otherwise, what would be the simplest way to paralelize these target operations?

Answer (score 0):

There are several [automatic parallelization tools for Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22automatic+parallelization%22+python), but I'm not sure if they are compatible with Numpy. It might be possible to parallelize these operations by combining a [Python-to-C++ translator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650243/convert-python-program-to-c-c-code) with an [automatic parallelization tool for C++](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+%22automatic+parallelization%22).